# How to add the diagonal line in depended vs predict plot in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, gplots

I performed regression analysis.
Now i need create plot `depended vs prediction`, where depend is initial values of dependent var(mpg) and predict is predicted values.

```
 house_test=lm(mpg ~ 1 + hp + wt, data=mtcars)

prediction <- as.data.frame(predict(house_test, mtcars, 
                                    interval = 'prediction',
                                    level = .95))


prediction$mpg <- mtcars$mpg


ggplot(prediction) +
  geom_ribbon(aes(mpg, ymin = lwr, ymax = upr), fill = 'lightskyblue', alpha = 0.5) +

  geom_point(aes(mpg, fit), alpha = 0.2) +
  labs(title = "interval 95%CI", y = "depend", x = "predict")
```

How can i add the  diagonal line(yellow color) in  depended vs predict plot?
Note Y axis is dependent var and X asis is prediction values.

i expect in output
[image: plot dep-pred]

Comment: Check out `geom_abline()`.

Comment: @moooh, yes, i have added geom_abline() and got the plot without points.  just check  ggplot(prediction) +
  geom_ribbon(aes(mpg, ymin = lwr, ymax = upr), fill = 'lightskyblue', alpha = 0.5) +
geom_abline()
  geom_point(aes(mpg, fit), alpha = 0.2) +
  labs(title = "interval 95%CI", y = "depend", x = "predict") . Maybe i did wrong?

Comment: @varimax, the code in your comment works for me; expect that there is a "+" missing between "geom_abline" and "geom_point"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ggplot(prediction) +
  geom_ribbon(aes(mpg, ymin = lwr, ymax = upr), fill = 'lightskyblue', alpha = 0.5) +

  geom_point(aes(mpg, fit), alpha = 0.2) +
  labs(title = "interval 95%CI", y = "depend", x = "predict") +

  geom_abline(intercept = 0, slope = 1, col="yellow")
```